# Side channel attack on FPGA AES engine

Tags: aes, side-channel-attack

I actually don't know if this is the right place where ask, but I try. The side channel attacks aren't a negligible problem. There are several ways to protect from these attacks its own IP inside the FPGA. My problem/curiosity it's focused on the AES engine inside the FPGA. The most important FPGA companies have an AES engine on silicon to decrypt the bitstream during the programmation of the device. In your knowledge, are there FPGAs more secure than others ? Is it possible to perform a side channel attack to the AES decrypter inside the FPGA ?

Comment: @fgrieu I've already seen but there isn't any reference to the most important FPGa companies ( Xilinx, Altera, Lattice ). For this reason I've asked here.

Comment: @fgrieu Again, I've seen papers that talk about a virtex II ( 130 nm process technology, pretty old) and none of those papers talk about the internal aes engine, they usually talk about a side channel attack on an IP.

Comment: See [this](https://www.emsec.rub.de/media/crypto/veroeffentlichungen/2011/11/28/Virtex4-5_DPA.pdf) work by Moradi et al for side channel analysis of bitstream encryption in Virtex-4 and Virtex-5.